# what's $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(a(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do you calculate

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\left(a(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)
$$
?

or more simply,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
$$
?

is it just zero?

or is it
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(
\frac{\partial a(x)}{\partial x}+a(x)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}
\right),\qquad
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
$$
respectively?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( a(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)=
\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+a(x)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
$$

but now, since $a$ and $f$ are not function of $f$ I don't understand what a derivative of this with respect to $f$ can means.